# Hard disk is empty after copying a file, then moving the HD to another computer

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, partitioning, hard-drive-recovery

I have a very strange issue. When I copy a file from my computer to a hard-disk everything is fine. However, when I use the hard-disk on other computers, it is empty. (The files are not hidden because the used space is 0.)

Then, when I re-open the hard-disk on the original computer, the files show up without a problem .

I have tried with other hard-disks and flash drives. I get the same result. After copying the file everything is fine, but when I put the flash drive on any other computer, I can see that there is no other change. (The used space is the same as it was. All my old files are there. Just the one that I copied is missing.)

It's like some one deleted everything but the file still shows up on the original computer.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Before removing a usb device, you should tell your OS that you will do that, so it can sync that device.

Right click and look for "safely remove".

Comment: impossible , there is no related between my problem and what are you saying .

Comment: Well, I've done it and I've sometimes forgotten to do it.  Did you sync the disks before removing them?

Answer (score 0):

Windows writes to disks and USB devices delayed, meaning when it thinks it has time to do it, not when you ask it to do. Until it is done writing, it fakes the content to you, so it looks like the files are on the disk, but they aren't yet.

You have to tell windows to finish writing before you remove the external device, depending on device type, this is done by 'Eject xxx' in the USB menu, or by 'remove xxx' in the explorer. If you can't get this to work (unfortunately pretty common in Windows 7), try as a last resort to shut windows down, and then remove the disk.

Comment: first I thought the same but i have tried with very small file 10kb , I got the same ,

Comment: and if So , how i can read the file again if i re put the flash on the source computer ? I run video from the HARD DISK  with 11 GB , and it works without problem

Answer (score -1):

It sound like first computer has encryption program or virus . while you are copying the data, the program encrypt the files and it wont work on other computers .

or maybe some type of virus trying to write in low bit level of your hard-disk without pointing the data to be showing ( it will act as deleted file ) .

Comment: -1. Encrypted file would still be visible, just unreadable. If the file was deleted, it would be deleted on all computers, not just some. Besides, that would be some weird behavior for a virus. It's neither destructive nor stealth, just inconvenient.

Comment: no, that's not true , it's not always encrypting mean you are not able to open a file or what ever you know ,at the end it depend to the method of encryption . some encryption methods can create a Hidden Encrypted Volume . it will act as deleted file . if you know how the deleting method is happen you will understand what i'm saying

Comment: when you delete file you are not deleting anything, it's just disappearing. but in real it wont remove until you wrote over it.  .what is really removed is the point of this file . but not the file it self. at the end, some encryption method can do the same to prevent stealing file from the employees

Comment: What about "used space is 0" with encryption?

Comment: Can you name any program that actually implements this kind of encryption (or rather steganography)? It doesn't sound safe. The file could be recovered by [carving](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_carving) or accidentally overwritten. Anyway, OP would probably know if they had such software on their computer.

Comment: this is what i'm saying , the method of encryption acting as deleted file. the method only removing the map to the data—not the data itself  (this is why he saw 0 space) . if so then how some program can recover the files even when the space is 0 :D . that mean the file is still in the hard-disk but only there mapping is removed, but in someway it's readable in the first computer .

Comment: Read up on file carving. It's typically used to recover accidentally deleted files or rescue contents of damaged partitions. Instead of relying on filesystem, carving involves scanning the drive byte by byte and looking for data that looks like recognized file types (for example [`FF D8 FF E0` may be beginning of a JPEG file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures)). What you're proposing is not encryption. Data is still there in plain text if you know where to look. It's [steganography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steganography).